# Autowiring with constructor

Tags: java, spring

Spring doc for Autowiring by constructor says that its same as byType, but for constructor arguments.

If thats the case, then why doesnt the following program fail:

**config.xml**

```
<bean id="traingle" class="org.practise.autowiring.Triangle" autowire="constructor" />

<bean id="pointA" class="org.practise.autowiring.Point">
    <property name="x" value="0"/>
    <property name="y" value="10"/>
</bean>

<bean id="pointB" class="org.practise.autowiring.Point">
    <property name="x" value="220"/>
    <property name="y" value="330"/>
</bean>

<bean id="pointC" class="org.practise.autowiring.Point">
    <property name="x" value="40"/>
    <property name="y" value="60"/>
</bean>
```

In the above case, I have 3 beans of same type(Point) that I'm trying to inject in the following class:

```
    public class Triangle {
    private Point pointA;
    private Point pointB;
    private Point pointC;

    public Triangle(Point pointA, Point pointB, Point pointC) {
        this.pointA = pointA;
        this.pointB = pointB;
        this.pointC = pointC;
    }
    public Point getPointA() {
        return pointA;
    }
    public void setPointA(Point pointA) {
        this.pointA = pointA;
    }
    public Point getPointB() {
        return pointB;
    }
    public void setPointB(Point pointB) {
        this.pointB = pointB;
    }
    public Point getPointC() {
        return pointC;
    }
    public void setPointC(Point pointC) {
        this.pointC = pointC;
    }


    public void draw() {
        System.out.println("Point A: " + getPointA().getX() + ", " + getPointA().getY());
        System.out.println("Point B: " + getPointB().getX() + ", " + getPointB().getY());
        System.out.println("Point C: " + getPointC().getX() + ", " + getPointC().getY());
    }
}
```

**Point**

```
public class Point {
private int x;
private int y;

public int getX() {
    return x;
}
public void setX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
}
public int getY() {
    return y;
}
public void setY(int y) {
    this.y = y;
}
```

}

**Executing the code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("org/practise/autowiring/spring-autowiring.xml");
    Triangle triangle = (Triangle) context.getBean(Triangle.class);
    triangle.draw();
}
```

It passes and prints the following:

```
Aug 18, 2013 2:04:56 PM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@43ee1619: startup date [Sun Aug 18 14:04:56 PDT 2013]; root of context hierarchy
Aug 18, 2013 2:04:56 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [org/practise/autowiring/spring-autowiring.xml]
Aug 18, 2013 2:04:56 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@13c6395b: defining beans [traingle,pointA,pointB,pointC]; root of factory hierarchy
Point A: 0, 10
Point B: 220, 330
Point C: 40, 60
```

When I change the wiring type to "byType", it throws the expected exception. Only in the above case it works fine. I'm using Spring 3.2

Comment: What's the definition of the `Point` class?

Comment: Well, it looks like the documentation hasn't been updated to specify that bean name resolution is used in addition to type resolution. You could submit an RFE to Spring.

Comment: @JohnFarrelly, updated the question with Point class

Comment: @JBNizet, so in essence, if it cannot find single reference, it falls back to "byName"?

Comment: I don't think so. To confirm, remove your setters and/or add traces to see what is passed to the constructor. My guess is that is uses the constructor arguments name to know which bean to inject (this feature is described here: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-ctor-arguments-name)

Comment: `<bean id="traingle" ` Is that traingle right?